# How to traverse through the values in a dictionary and get maximum value wherever the value is a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

I have a dictionary:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3], 'c': [8, 5]}
```

I want to get only the maximum value wherever there is a list in the value place of the dictionary. Like for this example, I want:

```
{'a':1, 'b': 3, 'c':8}
```

as the output.

I was doing:

```
for key in s_dict:
    x = s_dict.values()
    for elem in x:
        y = max(elem)
```

But, I'm getting an error:

```
  y = max(elem)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.
```

Could somebody please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: because half the time you're trying to do `max(1)` not `max([2,3])`. `1` is not iterable. Instead do: `try: y = max(elem) except TypeError: y = elem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and test whether each value is a list with [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> s_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3], 'c': [8, 5]}
>>> {k: max(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v for k,v in s_dict.items()}
{'c': 8, 'a': 1, 'b': 3}
>>>
```

Comment: not bad, though I prefer `if hasattr(v, '__iter__')`

Comment: Well, I went with `isinstance` because there is nothing to suggest that the values could be anything other than ints and lists.  Interesting fun fact though: you can make an iterable type without an `__iter__` method by overloading `__getitem__` instead.  So, `if hasattr(v, '__iter__')` would also fail if the values can be some other kind of iterable. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy's max(), then it doesn't matter whether the element is a list:

```
import numpy as np
for key in s_dict:
    x = s_dict.values()
    for elem in x:
        y = np.max(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `try/except`, as @AdamSmith suggested, in a generator function.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3], 'c': [8, 5]}
def foo(d):
    # use d.iteritems() for Python v2.x
    for k, v in d.items():
        try:
            yield k, max(v)
        except TypeError:
            yield k, v
```

Usage

```
>>> f = foo(d)
>>> f
<generator object foo at 0x03377198>
>>> dict(f)
{'a': 1, 'c': 8, 'b': 3}
>>>
>>> list(foo(d))
[('a', 1), ('c', 8), ('b', 3)]
>>>
```